# Decomposed source code from apk file, but it won't open in Android Studio

Tags: android, git

So my harddrive recently got wiped and I lost my source code for one of my projects, now I found a way to decompose the source code from the apk file but I can't get it to open in Android Studio. I am trying to upload this source code to GitHub but when I try to share it from Android Studio I get the error message "Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error =2, The system could not find the specified file".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: first of all you  can't get back java code form decompiling APK, only thing you can get is smali code. also you dont have Git installed in your computer. get it from https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Just downloaded Git awhile ago, should it work now?

Comment: restart android studio and it should work.

Comment: So I uploaded it, but it doesn't seem like my source code from the apk file has been uploaded in the new repo. Am I going to have to manually upload all the files I decomposed using the online decomposer?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project root folder in project structure and Git->Add (Ctrl+ALt+A) then commit and push all our files will be in the repo..

Comment: Add is grayed out, can't click it.